# How to remove the stacktrace from the standard ServiceStack error respose

Tags: c#, .net, servicestack

I'm just getting started with ServiceStack, and I'd like to find out if it's possible to remove the stacktrace from the standard error response.

I have tried shutting off debugmode without any luck:

```
public override void Configure(Funq.Container container)
{
    SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = false, });
}
```

Thanks a bunch!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

By default the configuration below only removes the StackTrace from being externally visible in your Web Service's response:

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = false, });
```

I've tested this again and it works as expected.

To disable Logging all together you can set [ServiceStack](http://www.servicestack.net) to use a NullLogFactory

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new NullLogFactory();
```

Alternatively you can control the granularity of all logging by creating your own [ServiceStack.Logging](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack.Logging) adapter and setting it in the same way:

```
LogManager.LogFactory = new MyCustomLogFactory();
```

Comment: Wonderful!  Thanks very much for the clarification and even more for developing ServiceStack.  Loving it.

Just hit it remotely and I get a 400 Bad Request.  Perfect.

Answer (score 1):

I was worried about the stack trace before and did some testing about it.

I found out that in the default case you don't need to set this option. If the project is built in Release then the stack trace is not in the response.