# ServiceStack: removing StackTrace from ResponseStatus

Tags: asp.net-mvc-3, c#-4.0, stack-trace, servicestack

I know the same question has been asked here : [How to remove the stacktrace from the standard ServiceStack error respose](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8453034/how-to-remove-the-stacktrace-from-the-standard-servicestack-error-respose)

but it does not matter whatever I tried , I could not remove the StackTrace from ResponseStatus even on remote requests.

```
SetConfig(new EndpointHostConfig { DebugMode = false, });
```

is not working or I could not make it work.Any advice could be very helpful.

thnx

Comment: As @mythz stated this should work. Please submit a failing test.

Comment: Actually there is no test , I just tried and DebugMode is still the same and in global.asax , I had to override Application_Error and implement error handling for specific request

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This does in-fact work as expected. [This is the LOC that makes it so](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/master/src/ServiceStack.ServiceInterface/ServiceBase.cs#L228):

```
if (EndpointHost.UserConfig.DebugMode)
{
    // View stack trace in tests and on the client
    responseStatus.StackTrace = GetRequestErrorBody() + ex;
}
```

Comment: Well, I set DebugMode as false but StackTrace is still there.if I set false,the StackTrace should be empty string or null, shouldn't it ?

Comment: After upgrading 3.9.5 version , it started to work. But I already implemented my handler on global.asax :) cheers,,